# How to return list of post model in flutter

Tags: flutter

This is example of my json response

```
[
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
    },
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "qui est esse",
        "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
    },
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 3,
        "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
        "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
    },
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 4,
        "title": "eum et est occaecati",
        "body": "ullam et saepe reiciendis voluptatem adipisci\nsit amet autem assumenda provident rerum culpa\nquis hic commodi nesciunt rem tenetur doloremque ipsam iure\nquis sunt voluptatem rerum illo velit"
    },
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 5,
        "title": "nesciunt quas odio",
        "body": "repudiandae veniam quaerat sunt sed\nalias aut fugiat sit autem sed est\nvoluptatem omnis possimus esse voluptatibus quis\nest aut tenetur dolor neque"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using `http` package. You can get the response body by `response.body`. after that you can decode the response to convert it into a list.

```dart
List<PostModel> postList = json.decode(response.body).map<PostModel>((post) {
  return PostModel.fromJson(post);
}).toList();
```

```dart
class PostModel {
  int userId;
  int id;
  String title;
  String body;

  PostModel({this.userId, this.id, this.title, this.body});

  PostModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    userId = json['userId'];
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    body = json['body'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['userId'] = userId;
    data['id'] = id;
    data['title'] = title;
    data['body'] = body;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<PostModel> postList = json.decode(response.body).map<PostModel>((post) {
```

return PostModel.fromJson(post);
}).toList();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).